# PowerShell Get all users in a SP Group from a subsite

Tags: 2010, powershell, groups

Is it possible to get all users in a subsite. I found a script online but I keep getting the URL/ID cannot be found. The same command essentially works for the site collection but it doesn't work on the subsite.

```
Get-SPSite http://server/sites/yoursite |
 Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb |
 Select -ExpandProperty Groups |
 Where {$_.Name -EQ "your group name here"} |
 Select -ExpandProperty Users |
 Select Name, Email
```

Can someone put me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Groups belongs to Root Site Collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get with your code when used for a subsite is because you use Get-Site with a subsite Url.
Instead of Get-SPSite use Get-SPWeb as below:

```
Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/yoursite |
Select -ExpandProperty Groups |
Where {$_.Name -EQ "your group name here"} |
Select -ExpandProperty Users |
Select Name, Email
```

The code above will find the group only if its created in that site. To find a group regardless where it's been created (root site or subsite) you have to use SiteGroups instead of Groups

```
Get-SPWeb http://server/sites/yoursite |
Select -ExpandProperty SiteGroups |
Where {$_.Name -EQ "your group name here"} |
Select -ExpandProperty Users |
Select Name, Email
```

Comment: My issue was, like you said, using `Get-SPSite` instead of `Get-SPWeb`. I also had to remove the `Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb` command. Thanks.